# the usage of "setkey" function to join table with common values in R

Tags: r, function, join, merge, inner-join

I have two the structure of one table is :

`id_station day Precipitaion
id_station_1    day Precipitaion
110000  233 12
110000  162 9
110000  223 15
110000  240 12
110000  276 3
110000  236 2
110000  244 9
110002  286 10
110002  179 19
110002  206 15
110002  143 11
110002  261 15`

the other structure of other column is :

`id_station_2   day_1   day_2   Number
110000  184 263 1
110000  109 200 2
110000  115 356 3
110000  20  299 4
110000  120 279 5
110000  195 320 6
110000  121 275 7
110002  165 311 8
110002  140 329 9
110002  184 258 10
110002  127 228 11
110002  28  304 12`

I want to get tird table with such structure:

the other structure of other column is :

`id_station  day Precipitaion    Number
110000  233 12  1
110000  162 9   2
110000  223 15  3
110000  240 12  4
110000  276 3   5
110000  236 2   6
110000  244 9   7
110002  286 10  8
110002  179 19  9
110002  206 15  10
110002  143 11  11
110002  261 15  12`

THe result must be with two filters: 
1)id stations should be equal (id_station_1=id_station_2)
2)day from first column should be between day 1 and day 2 from second column (day_1 < day < day_2 )

IF this conditions are met we sholud get the third table with 3 three columns from first table and fourth column from second. 
As I know it should be used with **setkey** function. But I couldn't understand how I should use it correctly.
Tell me please how Shoud I use setkey (or another fuction) in this varient?
Thank you!

Comment: google for the use of the function `foverlaps()` from the data.table package. A non-equi join is also an option... setkey as NEEDED when using `foverlaps`, but not when performing a non-equi join..

Answer (score 1):

A 'problem' is that you have multiple overlapping ranges...

Here is a way to catch them all... please re-order and rename columns as needed

```
#normal left non-equi join
dt2[ dt1, on = c( "id_station_2 == id_station_1", "day_1 <= day", "day_2 >= day"), allow.cartesian = TRUE ]
```

**sample data**

```
library( data.table )

dt1 <- fread("id_station_1    day Precipitaion
110000  233 12
110000  162 9
110000  223 15
110000  240 12
110000  276 3
110000  236 2
110000  244 9
110002  286 10
110002  179 19
110002  206 15
110002  143 11
110002  261 15")

dt2 <- fread("id_station_2   day_1   day_2   Number
110000  184 263 1
             110000  109 200 2
             110000  115 356 3
             110000  20  299 4
             110000  120 279 5
             110000  195 320 6
             110000  121 275 7
             110002  165 311 8
             110002  140 329 9
             110002  184 258 10
             110002  127 228 11
             110002  28  304 12")
```

You can also experiment on using `foverlaps()` from the same package..